# How do I stack certain columns and copy the others all the way down to fill the empty rows?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, multiple-columns

I'm quite new to python and am learning by applying what I know to automate some tasks in Excel.

Basically what I'm trying to do is take certain columns (ex: `columns J:Z`) and stack them below each other i.e. `column J` goes under `column J`, and then column L goes under the column J & K stack, so on and so forth.

I was able to achieve this by:

python

```
df1 = df1['December']\
          .append(df1['Jan 2017'])\
              .append(df1['Feb 2017'])\
                  .reset_index(drop=False)
```

But in the process it took out columns `A:I`. What I would like to accomplish is copy columns `A:I` rows `1 - 20` for each stack. The data is columnar and I'd like to convert it into rows for each column

Comment: For info, code blocks use back quotes, not the same as in "it's". I fixed them!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for pandas .stack(), .unstack(), or .melt().

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOkj5zOHwRE